# Can JConsole monitor webapps running in JDK1.4 and weblogic 8.1?

Tags: java, profiler, heap-memory, jconsole, jdk1.4

I want to monitor my web app build on JDK 1.4 and Weblogic server 8.1.
Currently i am unable to Jconsole it as Threads in local are GRAYED out.

Let me know any work around to monitor old apps. Is it possible to use Jconsole to monitor apps build under JDK 1.4, HOW ?

Comment: 1.4??? You know that is not supported for many years now, right?

Comment: I believe there should be some configurations by which we can monitor the threads and classes. Currently Jconsole do monitor the Heap/ Thread counts but not able to get Thread details and classes causing the heap to increase. If not JConsole let me know any other tool.